# Authenticate with Mifare Ultralight C on Lumia

Tags: win-universal-app, nfc, mifare, lumia

I'm trying to authenticate with an Ultralight C card on a Lumia device, a 640 in this case. I have the code and can successfully authenticate using the Emulator and an external Cardreader (Springcard Prox n Roll). The chipset (PN547) of the Lumia 640 (and other Lumia's) should be able to authenticate an Ultralight C card. When sending the authentication APBU I get a 6A 81 return (function not supported).  Of course unauthenticated reading and writing works.

What can I do to get this working, will it work on other Lumia's ? Is is the PCSC layer which is refusing the authentication and not the chipset ?

Any thoughts ?